# Нужно записать название фильма, учитывая то, что название может состоять из двух слов

Tags: c

Использую для этого fgets, но она некорректно работает.
Вот, как это отражается в консоли.

```
Меню:
1. Добавить кассету
2. Удалить фильм
3. Поиск фильма по его названию
4. Поиск фильма по его стране
5. Поиск кассет по дате
6. Изменить кассету
0. Выход
1
Номер видеокассеты: 1
Название фильма: Страна, где был снят фильм:
```

Т.е. сразу перепрыгивает на след. аргумент...

```
#include "structure.h"
#include "app.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int app(int *spin, system *library)  //определение функции app
{
    int mem = *spin;   
    printf("Номер видеокассеты: ");
    scanf("%d", &library[*spin].number);
    printf("Название фильма: ");
    fgets(library->name, *spin, stdin);
    printf("Страна, где был снят фильм: ");
    scanf("%s", library[*spin].country);
    printf("Продолжительность фильма: ");
    scanf("%d", &library[*spin].span);
    printf("Жанр фильма: ");
    scanf("%s", library[*spin].genre);
    printf("Дата приобретения кассеты (через пробел день месяц год): ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &library[*spin].day, &library[*spin].month, &library[*spin].year);
    (*spin)++;      //увеличиваем счетчик 
    if(*spin == mem + 1)  //проверка изменения состояния счетчика 
        printf("\nOK!\n");
    else
        printf("\nError!\n");
    return mem;
}
```

Comment: `fgets` для `stdin` это просто `gets`, если что.

Comment: @D-side, нет, у fgets есть параметр для размера буфера же?

Comment: @Qwertiy а, точно. Вспомнил, MSVC ещё постоянно ругался на этот факт и предлагал свой нестандартный... как он назывался... `_gets_s`?  То же самое, но с длиной буфера.

Comment: @D-side, вроде без подчёркивания в начале, но точно не помню.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй в `scanf`е вместо формата `%s` формат `%[^\r\n]` для чтения до конца строки. Рекомендую перед форматом поставить пробел, чтобы все пробельные символы, оставшиеся в буфере, пропустились.